# package managers

Tags: discussion

I noticed that [What are pros and cons for MacPorts, Fink and Homebrew?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/32724/237) has come up due to an edit.

This is really an opinion based question but the answers are reasonable enough at the moment and is a common question that I think we should keep it. But editing it could be problematic as it is opinion based.

The issue I have is that the highest ranked and also accepted answer has reasonable summaries of the pros and differences of the main managers but starts with a definitive answer saying  Homebrew is the best.

I would like to remove that recommendation, which is opinion based.

The answer probably should be community wiki but as the user hasn't been seen for 4 years that does not matter much.

A problem is that some of what are given as benefits are can be seen as problems e.g. whether the manager uses macOS tools or installs its own tools. Should that be put into edits?

Comment: There are a bunch of answers, and it seems worthwhile to read all of them. Anyway, we could also lock the question as "offtopic but has historic significance"